# How to convert functions outputting via callbacks to iterators?

Tags: rust, iterator

I have recursive functions that generate output via callback functions. I would like to convert these to iterators.

Here's one, [Heap's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm), which generates permutations of a list.

```rust
fn heap_go<const N: usize>(xs: &mut [usize; N], p: usize, callback: &impl Fn(&[usize])) {
    if p == 1 {
        callback(xs)
    } else {
        heap_go::<N>(xs, p - 1, callback);
        (0..p - 1).for_each(|i| {
            xs.swap(if p & 1 == 1 { 0 } else { i }, p - 1);
            heap_go::<N>(xs, p - 1, callback);
        });
    }
}

fn heap<const N: usize>(callback: impl Fn(&[usize])) {
    heap_go::<N>(&mut std::array::from_fn(|i| i), N, &callback)
}
```

I can turn this recursive algorithm into a loop, and then at points of output, save the state and emit an iterator value, but this obfuscates the simple expression of the algorithm itself. I can collect the values into memory and then iterate, but this consumes memory unnecessarily. Is there a better way?

Comment: I'm a tad confused. Do you want to turn this into a struct that implements the `Iterator` trait? Or are you talking more generally?

Comment: @PitaJ Something that implements `Iterator`, yes.

Comment: So what are you having trouble with? Turning it into a loop, or specifically going from there to an iterative struct?

Comment: @PitaJ Is there a way to turn this into an iterator without large structural changes that obfuscates the meaning of the algorithm?

Comment: Generally no. Does the looping version really look that bad?

Comment: Modifying the array and handing out references to it along the way is not allowed by the iterator interface anyways, so you would have to copy the array.

Comment: As I see, there is at most `N` levels of recursion. You can create array in stack using `N` and use it to prevent recursion without heap allocations.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @PitaJ in a comment « handing out references to it along the way is not allowed by the iterator interface ».
With [GATs](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2022/10/28/gats-stabilization.html) it would be in theory possible to rely on a `LendingIterator` trait, but for now the `for` loop and the standard functional utilities rely on the original `Iterator` trait.

At least, we can *mimic* the standard `Iterator` with a `.next()` function (in `HeapState` here) providing references, but this will be totally independent of the standard `Iterator` trait.
We will not be able to use the standard functional utilities with this workaround, and moreover, a `while let` construction should replace the `for` loop.

As a workaround, we can provide an `Iterator` exclusively referencing this `HeapState` (`HeapStateIter` here) in order to express a more conventional `for` loop.
The `Item`s provided by this iterator do not refer to the iterator itself but to the `HeapState` (as with the `Iter` or `IterMut` iterators dedicated to `slices`), which is allowed by the standard `Iterator` trait.
However, I am not really satisfied, since I had to introduce an ugly `transmute()` in order to pretend the lifetime refers to the `HeapState` and not to the `HeapStateIter`.
(Maybe someone more experienced than me could suggest a fix?)

Note also that the `.iter()` introduced here is a bit misleading, since we usually expect that the data we are iterating over will not be mutated; here the iterations will mutate the `HeapState` although the obtained `Item`s do not allow any mutation.

```rust
fn heap_go<const N: usize>(
    xs: &mut [usize; N],
    p: usize,
    callback: &mut impl FnMut(&[usize; N]),
) {
    if p == 1 {
        callback(xs)
    } else {
        heap_go::<N>(xs, p - 1, callback);
        (0..p - 1).for_each(|i| {
            xs.swap(if p & 1 == 1 { 0 } else { i }, p - 1);
            heap_go::<N>(xs, p - 1, callback);
        });
    }
}

fn heap<const N: usize>(mut callback: impl FnMut(&[usize; N])) {
    heap_go::<N>(&mut std::array::from_fn(|i| i), N, &mut callback)
}

struct HeapState<const N: usize> {
    a: [usize; N],
    c: [usize; N],
    i: usize,
}
impl<const N: usize> HeapState<N> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            a: std::array::from_fn(|i| i),
            c: [0; N],
            i: 0,
        }
    }
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&[usize; N]> {
        while self.i < N {
            match self.i {
                0 => {
                    self.i = 1;
                    return Some(&self.a);
                }
                i if self.c[i] < i => {
                    self.a.swap(if i & 1 == 0 { 0 } else { self.c[i] }, i);
                    self.c[i] += 1;
                    self.i = 1;
                    return Some(&self.a);
                }
                _ => {
                    self.c[self.i] = 0;
                    self.i += 1;
                }
            }
        }
        None
    }
    fn iter(&mut self) -> HeapStateIter<'_, N> {
        HeapStateIter { state: self }
    }
}

struct HeapStateIter<'a, const N: usize> {
    state: &'a mut HeapState<N>,
}
impl<'a, const N: usize> Iterator for HeapStateIter<'a, N> {
    type Item = &'a [usize; N];

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        unsafe { std::mem::transmute(self.state.next()) } // ugly!
    }
}

fn main() {
    const N: usize = 5;
    //
    let mut v1 = Vec::new();
    heap::<N>(|arg| {
        // println!("recursive: {:?}", arg);
        v1.push(arg.to_owned());
    });
    //
    let mut v2 = Vec::new();
    let mut heap_state = HeapState::<N>::new();
    while let Some(arg) = heap_state.next() {
        // println!("iter-like: {:?}", arg);
        v2.push(arg.to_owned());
    }
    println!("same as recursive: {:?}", v1 == v2);
    //
    let mut v3 = Vec::new();
    let mut heap_state = HeapState::<N>::new();
    for arg in heap_state.iter() {
        // println!("iterator: {:?}", arg);
        v3.push(arg.to_owned());
    }
    println!("same as recursive: {:?}", v1 == v3);
}
/*
same as recursive: true
same as recursive: true
*/
```

Comment: This does not address the requirement of not changing the code substantially.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman You are right, I was too focused on @PitaJ 's comment about the limitation of the standard `Iterator` trait. That being said, I guess that comparing the different formulations is probably a matter of personal preference. Who knowns? The author of the question could change their mind ;^)

Comment: @prog-fh Thanks very much for your effort. Unfortunately, as I suspected, "making it fit" into an iterator obfuscates the algorithm significantly, and the algorithm is already obtuse to begin with. The original code has much more alignment against a generator paradigm but unfortunately generators are unavailable in stable Rust.